# Transparent bitmap

Tags: graphics, blackberry, java-me, drawing, bitmap

I am having problem here with bitmaps..I want to remove the black background that my bitmap is having.

I am creating bitmap bitmap from byte array..and then setting the bitmap in BitMapField..but the image shown has a black background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you post some code? Without some specific code we can't really help you.

If you aren't yet, you should be using [`createAlpha`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#createAlpha%28int%29) from the [`Bitmap`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html) class.

Further explanation and help for common problems can be found in the [Blackberry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&thread.id=29702&view=by_date_ascending&page=1) [Support](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=233260) [Forum](http://rim.lithium.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=233113).

Answer (score 2):

Use this constructor to create the Bitmap - `Bitmap(int type, int width, int height)`
where type should be `Bitmap.ALPHA_BITDEPTH_8BPP`

Comment: Seems like it's wrong, can't use Bitmap.ALPHA_BITDEPTH_8BPP in Bitmap constructor, it's for createAlpha()...